# How to iterate over a particular column in excel using pyxl(python)

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and need you help.I am trying to write code that iterates through a particular column in excel using pyxl

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 
from openpyxl import load_workbook


d=pd.read_excel('workbook.xlsx',header=None)
wb = load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
```

SO here in the above example I have to go column J and display all the values in  the column.

Please help me solve this.

Also,I have the same column name repeated in my excel sheet..For Example "Sample" column name is available in B2 and also in J2..But I want to get all the column information of J2.

Please let me know how to solve this...

Thankyou ..Please reply

Comment: Please provide an example of your data, few rows for us to see.

Comment: Table 1 Column Name Table 2 Column Name
x_Table 1  Name        A_Table 2    Name
y_Table 1  id                B_Table 2     id

Hi yolo..please find the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new to python, you should [learn to read the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). There are tons of modules available and it will be quicker for you and easier for the rest of us if you make the effort first.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import cell as cellutils

## My example book simply has "=Address(Row(),Column())" in A1:J20

## Because my example uses formulae, I am loading my workbook with
## "data_only = True" in order to get the values; if your cells do not
## contain formulae, you can omit data_only
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook.xlsx", data_only = True)
worksheet = workbook.active
## Alterntively: worksheet = workbook["sheetname"]


## A container for gathering the cell values
output = []

## Current Row = 2 assumes that Cell 1 (in this case, J1) contains your column header
## Adjust as necessary
column = cellutils.column_index_from_string("J")
currentrow = 2

## Get the first cell
cell = worksheet.cell(column = column, row = currentrow)

## The purpose of "While cell.value" is that I'm assuming the column
## is complete when the cell does not contain a value

## If you know the exact range you need, you can either use a for-loop,
## or look at openpyxl.utils.cell.rows_from_range
while cell.value:
    ## Add Cell value to our list of values for this column
    output.append(cell.value)

    ##  Move to the next row
    currentrow += 1

    ## Get that cell
    cell = worksheet.cell(column = column, row = currentrow)


print(output)
""" output: ['$J$2', '$J$3', '$J$4', '$J$5', '$J$6', '$J$7',
            '$J$8', '$J$9', '$J$10', '$J$11', '$J$12', '$J$13', '$J$14',
            '$J$15', '$J$16', '$J$17', '$J$18', '$J$19', '$J$20']
```

Comment: You are super..Thankyou so much..I could learn few things from this

Comment: Hi Reid..One more question..In the excel file that I am doing there are some striked of fields ..How do I omit the striked off text in some of the fields

Comment: I'm glad that helps, but- again- please [check the docs so you don't have to wait for an answer](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html). According to that page, you can check the font style with `cell.font` and strikethrough is available via `cell.font.strike.`
And remember to mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark) so people who need it can find it and others who are answering questions don't need to check.